# How to scrape Google Streetview's timelapse view?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the years available and be able to click through and grab images from google streetview's timelapse view. example url: https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7560546,-73.9869468,3a,75y,213.28h,97.56t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sc1y9nJwHAUOEIJnwtnmpLQ!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3Dc1y9nJwHAUOEIJnwtnmpLQ%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D214.07529%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192?hl=en

The challenge is the the little pop up slider seems to be completely Javascript based vs. being actual divs or list items. How could I build a little program to click through these?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, I tested it in the browser console and it works:

```js
let timelaps = document.querySelectorAll('ul[aria-hidden] li button')
let date = document.querySelector("#timemachine div span:last-child")
let img_link = document.querySelector("#timemachine div img:first-child")
let show_btn = document.querySelector(`button[aria-label="Show historical imagery"]`)

show_btn.click()

Array.from(timelaps).forEach((el, idx) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        el.click(); 
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(date.textContent); 
            console.log(img_link.src)
        }, 500)
    }, 500 * idx);
});
```

Output:

```
May 2009
https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&authuser=0&hl=en&gl=uk&output=thumbnail&thumb=2&w=345&h=170&pitch=3.9682764767560457&ll=40.75602159547505%2C-73.98694447671228&panoid=FNZfi0DAAXXDNcTn0glS1Q&yaw=160.10522775141186
Jun 2011
https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&authuser=0&hl=en&gl=uk&output=thumbnail&thumb=2&w=345&h=170&pitch=3.9682764767560457&ll=40.75602159547505%2C-73.98694447671228&panoid=WGlebh2jM_JeT_REIQmBoQ&yaw=160.10522775141186
Jul 2011
https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&authuser=0&hl=en&gl=uk&output=thumbnail&thumb=2&w=345&h=170&pitch=3.9682764767560457&ll=40.75602159547505%2C-73.98694447671228&panoid=2jwmbqJv5YYy70VjK9YaSg&yaw=160.10522775141186
Aug 2011
https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&authuser=0&hl=en&gl=uk&output=thumbnail&thumb=2&w=345&h=170&pitch=3.9682764767560457&ll=40.75602159547505%2C-73.98694447671228&panoid=KGIAgcrR8OWSgIrxlvtwmw&yaw=160.10522775141186
Aug 2012
https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&authuser=0&hl=en&gl=uk&output=thumbnail&thumb=2&w=345&h=170&pitch=3.9682764767560457&ll=40.75602159547505%2C-73.98694447671228&panoid=ZK_mBAfOmDQ_1fik0r9xkQ&yaw=160.10522775141186
Aug 2013
https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&authuser=0&hl=en&gl=uk&output=thumbnail&thumb=2&w=345&h=170&pitch=3.9682764767560457&ll=40.75602159547505%2C-73.98694447671228&panoid=LjP8KRFgq-tjUU25CrKrlg&yaw=160.10522775141186
```

If you just need to click:

```js
let timelaps = document.querySelectorAll('ul[aria-hidden] li button')
let show_btn = document.querySelector(`button[aria-label="Show historical imagery"]`)

show_btn.click()

Array.from(timelaps).forEach((el, idx) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        el.click()
    }, 500 * idx);
});
```